# Regex for links like this?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to download every picture from a webpage. The pictures have a link like this:

```
http://konachan.com/image/3817c91e4f5db662df1b49c0ee846e90/Konachan.com%20-%20160286%20barioth%20monster_hunter%20tagme.jpg
```

First there is the

```
http://konachan.com/
```

then some stuff, a slash and again some stuff. After that comes the

```
Konachan.com
```

Then comes the point where I don't know any further, because the rest of the link consists of some numbers, letters, minuses, underscores and percentage-symbols. How do I define those?

My current Regex looks like this, but unfortunately I get only 1 result which has everything between the first and the last match in it.

```
(http://konachan.com/\w+/\w+/Konachan.com.+.(?:jpg|png|gif))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the remaining special chars to a character class and escape the dot to represent a literal dot. Add capturing groups `()` if necessary to capture the whole link.

```
http:\/\/konachan\.com\/\w+\/\w+\/Konachan\.com[-%\w]+\.(?:jpg|png|gif)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pD0nJ3/1)